# Bootstrap grid system with mixed display with different images attached

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, grid

Bootstrap grid system with mixed display with different images attached.
Please check attached pictures. Everytime if I use different images shown as mobile size, it shows three rows rather than 2 row. How can I solve this issue?

```
<div id="page-ad">
   <div class="container">
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $ad_img01[url]; ?>" alt="...">
          </a>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $ad_img02[url]; ?>" alt="...">
          </a>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $ad_img03[url]; ?>" alt="...">
          </a>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo $ad_img04[url]; ?>" alt="...">
          </a>
       </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[different images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFc7A.png),
[same images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkVMy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Bootstrap clearfix after the second col div

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $ad_img01[url]; ?>" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $ad_img02[url]; ?>" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>

  <!-- here -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <!--  -->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $ad_img03[url]; ?>" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php echo $ad_img04[url]; ?>" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```